# how to display how many times a button was click by php

Tags: php, html, css

I need help on how to display how many times my HTML button was click using php.

```
<div class="container">
        <form action="button.php" method="POST" class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT"/>
        </form>
    </div>


    <?php

        $btn=$_POST['submit'];

        $numb= 1;
        //my statement goes here
        do {$numb++;
        } while(isset($_POST['submit']));     

    ?>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a database to save the value.

Comment: `while(isset($_POST['submit']))` - What would ever cause this to become `false`?  Taking a step back... If you want to store information between page loads then you need to store that information somewhere outside of the page.  A database, a file, session state, a cookie, the hidden field you have here, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="button.php" method="POST" class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Increment the count value in the session variable
    if(isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
        $_SESSION['count']++;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
    }
}

// Display the count value
echo "Button was clicked ".$_SESSION['count']." time(s).";
?>
```